# Display my custom project to be selected just after clicking NEW menu

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Currently when i want to select my Custom project, it is has to be selected by NEW->OTHER..->My-Custom-Project.

Is it possible to display my custom project under NEW menu.
NEW->My-Custom-Project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have written a New Wizard for your custom project use the `org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions` extension point to add a 'new wizard shortcut' to display the wizard directly on the New menu.

Something like:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions"> 
    <perspectiveExtension 
        targetID="org.eclipse.ui.resourcePerspective"> 
        <newWizardShortcut id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.wizards.NewProjectCreationWizard"/>
```

The shortcut is specific to the perspective.

You may have to do a Perspective Reset (or Customize Perspective) to get the new shortcut to show.

Comment: Shortcut appears on File->New->My-Custom-Project.
But not as "Right Click on Navigator->New->My-Custom-Project".

Is it possible to get it as "Right Click on Navigator->New->My-Custom-Project"?

Comment: I'm not sure what controls those menus - it probably depending on exactly which view.

Comment: I am using "org.eclipse.ui.navigator.CommonNavigator"

Comment: Sorry, I have never used CommonNavigator so I don't know what it does.